# 'Text ' is not a valid value for the enum 'FieldType'

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, metadata-api, metadata

I am trying to create fields dynamically on a custom object. Field's metadata info taking from csv file. When I am uploading the file then I am getting callout exception from `MetadataService`.

> EXCEPTION_THROWN|[13432]|System.CalloutException: Web service callout
>   failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: 'Text ' is not a valid value
>   for the enum 'FieldType' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=

I have checked in my csv file all the values are fine. Text is also supported metadata type for customFields.

Here's my method:

```
public static void createCustomFields(string fieldName, string 
    System.debug('******fieldName**inside service*'+fieldName); 
    System.debug('******fieldLength**inside service*'+fieldLength);
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
    MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
    customField.fullName = fieldName;
    customField.label = fieldLabel;
    customField.type_x = fieldType;
    customField.length = fieldLength;
    System.debug('*******Custom Field values******');
    System.debug('*************'+customField);
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });              
    handleSaveResults(results[0]);
    system.debug('******results*****'+results);      
}
```

---

```
string fieldName, string fieldLabel,integer fieldLength, string fieldType
```

all these values are coming correctly in this method from csv file.

Issue in this line: `List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });`

Strange thing is when I run the same code from anonymous by passing hardcoded values it works fine and custom field get created.

Not sure what's wrong with csv file.

Attaching the snapshot of csv file.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I can see from  error message, you have trailing space in `Text(space goes here)`.

you need to remove that space before passing to API by using `normalizeSpace()` or `trim()` [String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) .

```
customField.type_x = fieldType;
```

change to

```
customField.type_x = fieldType.normalizeSpace();
```

---

it is better to sanitise string before passing to `createCustomFields` method:

```
YourClass.createCustomFields(fieldName, fieldLabel, fieldLength, fieldType.normalizeSpace());
```